# Understanding a step in Rudin's proof that the diameter of a subset in a metric space is equal to the diameter of the closure of the subset.

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that since $ E \subset Cl(E) $, $$ \text{diam}\hspace{1.1mm}E < \text{diam}\hspace{1.1mm}(Cl(E)). $$ The next step involves choosing an arbitrary $ \epsilon > 0$, and choosing $p \in \text{Cl}(E), q \in \text{Cl}(E)$. Now, he says by definition of $\text{Cl}(E)$, there are points $p',q'$ in E such that $d(p,p')< \epsilon, d(q,q')< \epsilon.$ This is where I am confused. Now, if $p,q$ are limit points of E then the previous statement necessarily holds. But, what if say, one of the points, say $p$, is an isolated point of $E$, i.e., $p\in E$ but $p$ is not a limit point of E. Then there need not be a $p'\in E$, such that $d(p,p')< \epsilon$, for an arbitrary $\epsilon$. I have tried to see if I have missed a result somewhere, like if the closure of a set is perfect, (closed and every point of the set is a limit point of the same), but I haven't come across any such result. Some of the other proofs that I have seen also seem to use the above statement. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

This is a duplicate of [If $p$ is an element of $\overline E$ but not a limit point of $E$, then why is there a $p' \in E$ such that $d(p, p') < \varepsilon$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175264/if-p-is-an-element-of-overline-e-but-not-a-limit-point-of-e-then-why-is?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is an isolated point of $E$ just take $p'=p$ in the proof.